# Error installing Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, ide

Trying to install Force.com IDE and I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.api_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.core_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.core.compatibility.auth.equinox_29.0.0.201310181333.jar.
Read timed out
```

What can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had to copy the links that weren't reading the repository correctly and paste them into the search bar on the browser. It downloaded the missing files and then I moved these files into the Eclipse plugins folder. When I ran it again it was successful.

Comment: I'm in the same boat - but my error reads: "Unable to read repository at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/content.xml.
Cannot assign requested address: connect". Any ideas??? Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution. This is more of an Eclipse error, whereby eclipse was trying to use IPv6 to connect. See details here: http://www.flintstudio.com/blog/quick-tip-eclipse-repository-problems-windows-8/#.UvccyfmSz_U. Simply adding  "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to eclipse.ini fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [installation instructions](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation), if you receive a "read timed out" error, you may need to configure your proxy settings.

> Configure Eclipse to use your proxy server. These settings can be found in your Eclipse Preferences, under General > Network Connections.

Comment: There is no proxy server. I have looked through the ipconfig /all and there is no text next to 'Primary dns suffix'. Anything else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: After I added my proxy settings, this worked a treat. A good step by step guide on how to do this is here: http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse
Goto
Window
Preferences
General
NEtwork settings
Check your proxy settings,if not using proxy,use direct option
try again

Comment: ram, you may want to note that you've posted an answer to a 2yr old question. Also, the user who posted the question later posted an answer with the solution that solved his problem. The solution isn't what you've posted as an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was hanging up partway through every time on the same jar. (http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42/plugins/com.salesforce.ide.core_36.0.0.201601221512.jar)

I manually downloaded that jar and copied to the plugins folder.  Next try the install completed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install at work. Kept receiving an error. So, I disconnected my laptop from my work network, turned on my iPhone hotspot, and all worked per normal. The network was the problem for me.

-Windows 10
-Eclipse Neon.3
-Force.com - https://developer.salesforce.com/media/force-ide/eclipse45